# Given a path in Vault how do I find who can access it?

Tags: hashicorp-vault

Given a policy, I can see what paths it provides access to.

However, I would like to know the opposite: given, a path I want to known which policies define access to it and which users/identities/group have these policies assigned to them?

In short, given a path who can do what with that.

How can I find that with vault command-line client or UI?

Answer (score 1):

The better way is to use the HTTP API like in the following example:

```
REST_URL="https://VAULT-SERVER/v1"
VAULT_TOKEN="VAULT_TOKEN"
VAULT_PATH="identity"

for p in $(curl --silent --header "X-Vault-Token: $VAULT_TOKEN" --request LIST $REST_URL/sys/policies/acl | jq --raw-output .data.keys[])
do
    echo ""
    echo "$p"
    echo ""

    curl --silent --header "X-Vault-Token: $VAULT_TOKEN" --request GET $REST_URL/sys/policies/acl/$p | jq .data.policy | grep --color $VAULT_PATH
done
```

Result:

> admin
>
> "... # Manage identities\npath "identity/*" {\n
> capabilities = ["create", "read", "update", "delete",
> "list", "sudo"]\n}\n\n ..."
>
> default
>
> "... # Allow a token to look up its own entity by id or
> name\npath "identity/entity/id/{{identity.entity.id}}" {\n
> capabilities = ["read"]\n}\npath
> "identity/entity/name/{{identity.entity.name}}" {\n  capabilities =
> ["read"]\n}\n\n\n ..."
>
> root